# Disable some css rules

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I have a project where I write some interfaces, which are embedded in other interfaces. If I use bootstrap, pure bootsrap rules are in conflict with rules of other css files. So I build bootstrap with all it's rules wrapped in .use_bootstrap class. Now in my interfaces I write all code inside `<div class="use_bootstrap">...</div>`.But some css rules of other interfaces are affect my interfaces. Is it possible to block all rules inside .use_bootstrap, which don't contain .use_bootstrap class in selector?

Comment: Maybe using `property: value !important` will solve the problem - http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Which Bootstrap rules are in conflict?

Comment: `!important` is a very blunt knife.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
:not(.use_bootstrap)
```

outside your non-bootstrap rules.